# C++ class member pointer to global function

Tags: c++, class, function-pointers, global

I want to have a class which has as a member a pointer to a function

here is the function pointer:

```
typedef double (*Function)(double);
```

here is a function that fits the function pointer definition:

```
double f1(double x)
{
    return 0;
}
```

here  is the class definion:

```
class IntegrFunction
{
public:
    Function* function;
};
```

and somewhere in the main function i want to do something like this:

```
IntegrFunction func1;
func1.function = f1;
```

But, this code does not work.

Is it possible to assign to a class member a function pointer to a global function, declared as above? Or do I have to change something in the function pointer definition?

Thanks,

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: How does it "not work"? Do you get a compiler error? If so, what is it?

Comment: The answer might be easier for us to find if you would supply a complete example. You are *so* close, it would only take just a few more lines to make it complete. Also, can you tell us what you mean by "does not work?" Do you get an error from the compiler? Linker? Do you get a run-time behavior different than what you expect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace this:

```
class IntegrFunction
{
public:
    Function* function;
};
```

with this:

```
class IntegrFunction
{
public:
    Function function;
};
```

Your typedef already creates a pointer-to-function. Declaring `Function* function` creates a pointer-to-pointer-to-function.

Comment: Thanks, I understood my mistake and my code works now. I should be more careful next time.

Answer (score 4):

Just replace

```
Function* function;
```

to

```
Function function;
```

Answer (score 2):

You declare the variable as `Function* function`, but the `Function` typedef is already a typedef for a pointer. So the type of the function pointer is just `Function` (without the *).

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
typedef double (*Function)(double);
```

by

```
typedef double Function(double);
```

to typedef the function-type. You can then write the `*` when using it.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use the address-of operator to obtain a function pointer in Standard C++03.

```
func1.function = &f1;
```

Comment: No you don't.  The `&` is necessary for taking the address of a member function but not for a nonmember function.