# Class non-static method pointer to global function

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14

I'm trying to point a class method to a global function, i've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6005024/c-class-member-pointer-to-global-function)
but how i can't do it without instance?.

Consider this:

```
class x
{
    public:
        int(x::*GetVal)(int);
};

int RtX(int a)
{
    return a * 4;
}

// declaration
int(x::*GetVal)(int) = (int(x::*)(int))&::Rtx; // :: global? // error

int main()
{
    x a;
    cout << (a.*GetVal)(4) << endl; 
}
```

This returns me the error:

> [Error] invalid cast from type 'int (*)(int)' to type 'int
>   (x::*)(int)'

Comment: Use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) instead.

Comment: As for your error, member function are not the same as non-member functions. Member functions need an instance of an object to be called, non-member functions don't. That object instance is often passed as a hidden argument to the member function, and since non-member function won't have that hidden argument they are simply not compatible in any way, shape or form.

Comment: as an alternative to bind you can also use a lamba where you call the member function and store it in a `std::function` object.

Comment: another thing, which makes this whole a bit more unclear. What are you trying to do? you cannot set a function pointer to a class which has no instance when it is not static. You need an instantiation. Do you want a static function pointer or a default one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x::GetX` is a pointer to member.  These are deeply complicated beasts, and you can't get them to point to non-member functions.  The following code will work:

```
#include <iostream>

int RtX(int a)   // Global non-member function
{
    return a * 4;
}

class x
{
    public:

        int(x::*GetVal)(int);

        // This is an instance member function which acts as a proxy and calls the
        // the global function
        int RtX(int a) { return ::RtX(a); }
};


int main()
{
    x a;
    a.GetVal =&x.RtX;  // Assign the member variable.  Could do this in the
                       // constructor.  **NOTE** No casts!
    std::cout << (a.*GetVal)(4) << std::endl; 
}
```

If you find yourself reaching for a cast when dealing with function pointers and pointers-to-member-functions, **stop** - you are almost certainly doing it wrong, and while it will compile, it is very likely not to run properly.

Alternatively, as noted in the comments, use `std::function`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int RtX(int a)
{
    return a * 4;
}

class x
{
public:
    std::function<int(int)> GetVal;

    // Initialize GetVal in the constructor.
    x() : GetVal(RtX) 
    {}

    // Alternatively, you can initialize the variable in with a default
    // initialization.  You can also declare the member const if you don't want to 
    // change it later.

    const std::function<int(int)> gv = RtX;

    /*
};

int main()
{
    x a;
    std::cout << a.GetVal(4) << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: Good point.  Didn't notice the "non-static" in the title.  I'll amend.

Comment: I knew that was possible being static, but i wanted to know if possible doing non-static. thanks a lot for help.

Comment: What you had wasn't possible with static.  I've updated for non-static.

Comment: It is the only solution quickly, i do frame as the solution, @Martin Bonner please you can tell me if it's possible declare it out of the class, something like x::gv = Rtx; (out of the class).?

Comment: It's worth distinguishing between "declare" and "define".  A *declaration* says that a thing (class, function, variable) exists.  A *definition* says exactly "what" it is (where "what" varies between class/function/variable).  A definition is also a declaration.  For variables, definition is about give the variable a memory address.  For a static member variable, you must declare it in the class, and declare it outside the class; the definition can also give it a value.

Comment: For a non-static member variable, you must declare it in the class, and there is no way to "define" it.  The declaration (inside the class) can also give it a default initializer.  A constructor can also initialize a non-static member variable.

Comment: ... which is a long way of saying "No, you can't write `x::gv = Rtx` outside the class for a non-static member".  @nikomaster

Comment: thanks a lot, i was just saying that for use it when is defined out of header file.

Answer (score 1):

Non static member functions need an instance in order to be called. You might consider using a static function member instead and if you also use `std::function`, you might get a simple code to assign your member function without instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int RtX(int a)
{
    return a * 4;
}

class x
{
public:
    static std::function<int(int)> GetVal;
};

std::function<int(int)> x::GetVal = RtX;

int main()
{
    x a;
    std::cout << (a.GetVal)(4) << std::endl;
}
```